# Change source button disabled in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am facing a problem with a Power BI book.

I would like to edit the source of a file. Basically it is the same file of the book, but this book was sent from another person and I would like to make some changes.

In this case I cannot edit the source of the file. I usually do it without problems but not this time.

Why is the button disabled? Any suggestion?

[image: Screen]

Comment: Try going into the power query editor, selecting the Source by clicking on the cog, and see if you can edit it from there

Comment: Hi Jonee, what do you mean clicking on the cog?

Comment: The little setting cog, looks like a gear

Comment: Thanks Jonee, it works. The problem is that i must replace datasource for every sheet and I can't select just one datasource for all. Any suggest?

Comment: No you'll have to do it for all the sheets. What I do as standard is parameter the data source connection to allow easy switching.. example https://jlsql.blog/2019/01/16/power-bi-parameters-data-sources/